# Single event handler for four button clicks

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in javascript. How to use single event handler for four buttons. Both html and js should be in single page. Thanks in advance.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script> 
        myFunc() { 
            var fired_button = $(this).val(); alert(fired_button); 
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <input type="button" value="one" onClick="myFunc()"><br> 
    <input type="button" value="two" onClick="myFunc()"><br> 
    <input type="button" value="three" onClick="myFunc()"><br> 
    <input type="button" value="four" onClick="myFunc()"><br> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What's your problem in your code this is the concern.

Comment: *"full code please"* ....What ???? Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective is for you to write the code and we help with specific problems

Comment: _single event handler for four buttons_. What are you trying to achieve from this ? what will happen if i click the button ? it will trigger the alert or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `jquery`, you don't need the `onclick` attribute, just add a class that is similar for all buttons. And **DO NOT** forget to add the `js` file of `jquery` above all `js` files

```js
$('.someClass').click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="someClass" type="button" value="one"><br>
<input class="someClass" type="button" value="two"><br>
<input class="someClass" type="button" value="three"><br>
<input class="someClass" type="button" value="four"><br>
```